# Access variable from included template in Jinja2?

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2

I'm developing in app engine.

I have a parent template with this:

```
{% set active_page = 'linked_accounts' -%}

{% block side_column %}
    {% include 'blocks/settings_sidebar.html' %} 
{% endblock %}
```

settings_sidebar contains

```
<h4>Settings</h4>
<hr>
{{active_page}}
<ul class="side_navigation">
    <li><a class="{% if 'my_account' == active_page %}active{% endif %}" href="/my_account">My Account</a></li>
    <li><a class="{% if 'linked_accounts' == active_page %}active{% endif %}" href="/linked_accounts">Linked Accounts</a></li>
</ul>
```

My problem is that active_page is empty. The docs state that by default includes include their parent scope, and yet that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: Which docs? Link please.

Comment: Which template do you render? What is in your child template?

Comment: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#include
"Included templates have access to the variables of the active context by default. For more details about context behavior of imports and includes see Import Context Behavior."

Comment: My parent template is the one being rendered, the child template is the settings_sidebar code I quoted above.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Figured it out. I had to add scoped to the block declaration or the include didn't have variable access.

Comment: Using `{% include 'file' with context %}` ?

Comment: Please describe how you did it.